# Change Orientation of Bluestack : portrait/landscape mode

Tags: android, orientation, bluestacks

if using the emulator, press CTRL-F12 we will change  portrait or landscape mode . How can i do this with BlueStack ?

Comment: try to change view of `bluestack.. that could be useful

Comment: i'm irritated this is not the bluestack docs

Comment: Guys does this also fix the upside down images in bluestack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This...

**Go to your notification area in the taskbar.**

**Right click on Bluestacks Agent>Rotate Portrait Apps>Enabled.**

There are several options available..

> a. **Automatic** - Selected By Default - It will rotate the app player in portrait mode for portrait apps.
>
> b. **Disabled** - It will force the portrait apps to work in landscape mode.
>
> c. **Enabled** - It will force the portrait apps to work in portrait mode only.

This May help you..

Comment: what key should i press to rotate? i have enabled the Rotate Portrait Apps

Comment: I'm searching for a way to rotate the window by force (manual by the user). Not to enable rotation by apps.

Comment: There is no Bluestacks Agent on the notification area. There is only "App player online" and the only option is Exit.

Comment: I can't find the agent on mac

Comment: @Pedro77 same here. I installed Rotation control app which worked fine. M.Zain suggested that in another answer.

Comment: i don't see any "bluestacks agent" , and I tried right clicking on everything in the win10 window border and nothing shows any rotation options.

Comment: @DavidJeske This is very old answer and Bluestacks have been changed so much after that. I am not using Bluestacks any more. Please check another answer.

Answer (score 36):

This works for me for BlueStacks 4:

- Install "Rotation Control" app
  [image]
- Enable it to appear onto taskbar; optionally with system start
  [image]
- Whenever you want to rotate the screen, just pull down the task bar, and give it a go
  [image]

Comment: So awesome! Thank you

Comment: Should be voted as the best answer considering it helps in far more use cases.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the step:

1. Install the Nova theme in bluestack
2. go into Nova setting -> look and feel -> screen orientation -> Force Portrait -> go to Home screen

You are done! :)

Answer (score 1):

The newest version of BlueStacks has the ability to rotate the screen.  Open the app and there's an icon in the lower right to rotate.

Answer (score 1):

**New version 4.100.x.xxxx**

Try this:

More Apps **>** Android Settings **>** Accessibility **>** Auto-rotate screen = **Enabled**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also change resolution of your bluestacks emulator. 
For example from 800x1280 to 1280x800

Here are instructions for [how to change the screen resolution](https://druss.co/2014/08/how-to-bluestacks-change-screen-resolution/).

To change screen resolution in BlueStacks Android emulator you need to edit two registry items:

1. Run regedit.exe
2. Set new resolution (in decimal):

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\BlueStacks\Guests\Android\FrameBuffer\0\Height`

and

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\BlueStacks\Guests\Android\FrameBuffer\0\Width`

Kill all BlueStacks processes.

Restart BlueStacks

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

On a newer version, go to setting advance, display, display resolution then change it to portrait and restart the blue stack app.

Answer (score -3):

I install go launcher on mine, (Windows 8)=> preferences => Screens => Screen orientation => vertical (disable QWE keyboard)